# Carousel, the image is resized when I add the class "col-lg-6"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this code below. When I add the class "col-lg-6" to the images in the carousel, I get an strange effect when sliding: the image is resized right before be stopped. Any help?

Here you have the site where happens: [www.ziiweb.com](http://www.ziiweb.com)

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active row">
        <img src="images/responsive3.png" class="col-lg-6"/>
      </div>
      <div class="item row">
        <img src="images/responsive3.png" class="col-lg-6"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `<img>` in a `<div>` instead of applying the `.col-6-lg` class directly.

E.g.:

```
<div class="item row">
    <div class="col-6-lg">
        <img src="images/responsive3.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: anyway I have realized now that the image is placed a bit to the right (like a little jump) right after stopping the slide.